# jquery ajax issue in IE 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have a small jquery mobile based application and I am facing the following problem in IE 9. I am downloading certain files in my app and these files have absolute path with ip address:
    http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/folder1/folder2/file.json

Now, the issue is that if  I call up the web app via website address:
    www.exampleaddress.com

then the ajax call to download the file fails but if I call the website via ip address:

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/folder1/webapp.html, then the ajax call works fine, without any problem.

I am having this issue only in IE 9, otherwise, I have no problem in other browser such as Firefox, Safari, Chrome etc.
How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're hitting the browser's "Same Origin" security features that prevent Javascript from loading cross-domain data (obviously the browser has no idea that the IP address and the domain are actually the same site).

The big question is why do you have hard-coded absolute paths with the IP address in the code? If they weren't hard coded that way, you wouldn't have a problem.

The solution to your problem is not to hard code the domain. It seems from the question that everything is in the same site, so just drop the hard-coded IP address from the URLs and you'll be fine.

So your URL would look like this: `/folder1/folder2/file.json`

This should work either way you access the site.